# Load JSON to Highchart Series

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I'm trying render a column chart using json for xAxis categories and the series. Unfortunately no column chart been generated as shown in picture below.

[image: Highchart with no column bar]

Here is my JSON structure (already validate using JSON validator online)

```
{
    "Graph": {
        "Series": [
            {
                "name": "John",
                "data": [
                    "51",
                    "84",
                    "61",
                    "45",
                    "51",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "53",
                    "83",
                    "50",
                    "41",
                    "45",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "40",
                    "52",
                    "60",
                    "48",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "60",
                    "0",
                    "67",
                    "58",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Doe",
                "data": [
                    "1",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "1",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "1",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "0"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Categories": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4",
            "5",
            "6",
            "7",
            "8",
            "9",
            "10",
            "11",
            "12",
            "13",
            "14",
            "15",
            "16",
            "17",
            "18",
            "19",
            "20",
            "21",
            "22",
            "23",
            "24",
            "25",
            "26",
            "27",
            "28",
            "29",
            "30"
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my javascript

```
var dchart = {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: []
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Applicants'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y}</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {                        
            groupPadding: 0.1,
            pointPadding:0.1,
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function () {
                    return false; 
                }
            }
        },
        series: {
            dataLabels:{
                enabled:true,
                formatter: function() {
                    if(this.y>0){
                        return '<div style="text-align:center; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-weight:bold;">' + this.y + '</div>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: []
}

$.getJSON("<%=request.getContextPath()%>/c/MonthlyGraphAjax?method=ApplicantByDaily", function(data){
    /*xAxis categories*/
    for(var x=0;x<data.Graph.Categories.length;x++){
        dchart.xAxis.categories.push(data.Graph.Categories[x])
    }

    /*series*/
    for(var z=0;z<data.Graph.Series.length;z++){ 
        dchart.series.push(data.Graph.Series[z])
    }
    $("#columnGraphContainer").highcharts(dchart)

})
```

Can anyone help me solved this problem? I think the below code causing the problem

```
/*series*/
    for(var z=0;z<data.Graph.Series.length;z++){ 
        dchart.series.push(data.Graph.Series[z])
    }
```

Sorry for the inconvinience, here is the jsfiddle link for clear view of my problem. [Highchart With No Column Bar](http://jsfiddle.net/intoxicatedcandle/4fhxsjs8/)

Comment: please create a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HighCharts was expecting numeric values for the data series, but received strings instead and didn't know how to display those on the graph.  If you change your input from type String to type Number, it will fix your problem.

```
"Series": [
    {
        "name": "John",
         "data": [
             51,
             84,
             61,
             ...
         ]
    }
]
```

I've forked your fiddle here with a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/autoboxer/s8symkdz/.

Cheers,
autoboxer